# Simplifying Linq to Object result

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am not sure if the word "Simplifiying" is suitable in this context or not? But, I have a Linq Query lile below :

```
result.FIRSTOBJECT
   .Select(x => x.SECONDOBJECT
       .Select(y => y.THIRDOBJECT
           .Where(j => j.Key.Contains("Something"))));
```

[image]

And the result object I get is something like above screen-shot.

**My Question**: Is there a way that I can make this result to NOT be so nested?

Comment: Why do you care for this? Any Linq-method just returns an iterator, not the actual values. Only when you call `ToList` or `ToArray` or even `foreach` the actual query is executed producing the result-values.

Comment: Because, I need the final result, and the code becomes super ugly to select that final result. I tried doing a ToList(), but then it become 3 nested List again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to flatten the sequences? Then you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var allMathingThirdObjects = result.FIRSTOBJECT
    .SelectMany(x => x.SECONDOBJECT.SelectMany(y => y.THIRDOBJECT))
    .Where(j => j.Key.Contains("Something"));
```

You can loop the result in a `foreach` or create a collection(f.e. with `allMathingThirdObjects.ToList()`) or select the first one:

```
var firstMatchingThird = allMathingThirdObjects.FirstOrDefault(); // null if no match
```

or select the `Key` property into a single string:

```
string allMatchingThirdKeys = String.Join(", ", allMathingThirdObjects.Select(j => j.Key));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectMany` instead

```
result = result.FIRSTOBJECT
.SelectMany(x => x.SECONDOBJECT
   .SelectMany(y => y.THIRDOBJECT
       .Where(j => j.Key.Contains("Something"))));

var finalresult = result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You could shorten by replacing `Where` with `FirstOrDefault`, which will accept the same predicate as `Where`.